# I have multiple versions of Python installed, probably by accident. How can I keep the one install associated with Pip and delete the broken one?

Tags: python, uninstallation

I have multiple versions of Python installed, as seen by Command Prompt here. One is associated with Pip and is the one I need to use to do Python work. The other... I'm not sure how it got there.

It's confusing sometimes since one uses `python` to do commands in the terminal and one uses `py` to use the terminal, but only `python` uses pip.

I want to uninstall `py.exe` but I don't want to break `python.exe`.

Is there a safe way to do this?

Picture of my command prompt window showing the two different installs: (You can see that `pip` corresponds with `python`: [CMD window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyNi8.png)

[I went to Add or Install programs but noticed two different versions, and I don't know which is which. I think it's the one with the larger filesize but I want to be super safe and do it with the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GLIO.png)

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu, do not remove the other python, it can break a lot of stuff

Comment: I'm on Windows 10.